# Toolbar is not shown in android application

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I have recently started to migrate my old app to material design and decided to use toolbar instead of actionbar for more customization.I tried to add toolbar to only one activity with following code :

**layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:background="@drawable/background_tabs" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager pager;
    private MyPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyApp.tracker().send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder("ui", "open")
        .setLabel("main")
        .build());
        // Set a ToolBar to replace the ActionBar.
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

}
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <!-- your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/redLatest</item>
        <!-- darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/redLatest_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/redLatest</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyActionBarDropDown</item>
    </style>
```

Now when i run the above code I don't get action bar in my activity which is fine, but toolbar is also not showing up which is wierd. I know I might be doing some silly mistake which I am not able to find out.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added the view in `RelativeLayout`, hence you should specify where they have to be positioned. Since you have not specified it for the `TabLayout` the `Tablayout` is overlapping the `Toolbar`. Just add `android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"` in the `TabLayout`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:background="@drawable/background_tabs" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:background="@drawable/background_tabs" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```